# Use dplyr to calculate percentage and frequency of occurrence of two groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, percentage

I'm learning dplyr and have searched for solutions from similar posts but found none with this combination of problems.

Here is an example data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(sampleID = c(rep("sample1",2),
                                 rep("sample2",3),
                                 rep("sample3",4)),
                     species = c("clover","nettle",
                                 "clover","nettle","vine",
                                 "clover","clover","nettle","vine"),
                     type = c("vegetation","seed",
                              "vegetation","vegetation","vegetation",
                              "seed","vegetation","seed","vegetation"),
                     mass = sample(1:9))

    > df
  sampleID species       type mass
1  sample1  clover vegetation    9
2  sample1  nettle       seed    4
3  sample2  clover vegetation    7
4  sample2  nettle vegetation    1
5  sample2    vine vegetation    2
6  sample3  clover       seed    6
7  sample3  clover vegetation    3
8  sample3  nettle       seed    8
9  sample3    vine vegetation    5
```

I need to return a data frame that calculates percent mass for each unique species/type combination, and I need percent frequency of species/type occurrence within sampleIDs

So the solution for the species/type of vine/vegetation in this example would be
Percent mass = (5+2)/(sum(mass))
and the percent frequency would be 2/3 since that combination did not occur in sample1.

To start I tried different combinations such as:

```
df %>%
  group_by(species,type) %>%
  summarize(totmass = sum(mass))  %>%
  mutate(percmass = totmass/sum(totmass))
```

but that gives a 100% mass for vine/vegetation?  Also I would not know where to go from there to get the percent frequencies based on sampleID.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your denominators are. When you say "percent mass for each unique species/type combination", and give the `5 + 2` example, the numerator is clear. Is the deonominator the sum of mass.... within the sample? within the same type? within the same species? In the whole data frame?

Comment: Ditto for "percent frequency". You say *"and the percent frequency would be 2/3 since that combination did not occur in sample1."* - so is percent frequency the *number of samples with a particular species:type  combination / total number of samples*? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I got you right but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(sampleID = c(rep("sample1",2),
                              rep("sample2",3),
                              rep("sample3",4)),
                 species = c("clover","nettle",
                             "clover","nettle","vine",
                             "clover","clover","nettle","vine"),
                 type = c("vegetation","seed",
                          "vegetation","vegetation","vegetation",
                          "seed","vegetation","seed","vegetation"),
                 mass = sample(1:9))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  # Add total mass
  add_count(wt = mass, name = "sum_mass") %>%
  # Add total number of samples
  add_count(nsamples = n_distinct(sampleID)) %>%
  # Add sum_mass and nsamples to group_by
  group_by(species, type, sum_mass, nsamples) %>%
  summarize(nsample = n_distinct(sampleID), 
            totmass = sum(mass), .groups = "drop")  %>%
  mutate(percmass = totmass / sum_mass,
         percfreq = nsample / nsamples)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#>   species type       sum_mass nsamples nsample totmass percmass percfreq
#>   <chr>   <chr>         <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 clover  seed             45        3       1       6   0.133     0.333
#> 2 clover  vegetation       45        3       3      19   0.422     1    
#> 3 nettle  seed             45        3       2      12   0.267     0.667
#> 4 nettle  vegetation       45        3       1       1   0.0222    0.333
#> 5 vine    vegetation       45        3       2       7   0.156     0.667
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  How would you include Standard Error into the tibble?